# properties of $\min(x_1...x_n)$

Tags: metric-spaces, algorithms, normed-spaces, maxima-minima

I want to take measurements of algorithm performance. I have two algorithms A and B that run one after the other (composition)

I want to measure how well the composition of algorithms is better than the algorithms individually.

I propose to get run times of A and B individually as rA and rB and their run times when composed together as prA and prB (pr for partial run time)
and take the min(prA/rA, prB/rB) as a performance metric.

What properties does min(x,y) have? I know max(x,y) gives the $L^{\infty}$ norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$ but what about min? What other performance metrics are good for comparing a composition of algorithms?

Comment: I wanted to note that taking min may be a bad idea since we may have min(1,.5)= min(.5,.5) but clearly .5 run time ratio for both algorithms A and B is better than one, say A,  with .5 ratio and the other, say B,  with no improvement. Either way, what are properties of min(x,y)? I was also thinking of a performance metric like ax+by where a and b are constant weights and x and y are variables. what are properties of ax+by? certainly we get equivalence classes of slanted lines.

Comment: Also, how about (prA+prB)/(rA+rB)?